# Why is my AWS Certificate self-signed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

- I have instantaudiobook.co registered at Name Cheap and pointing to AWS
  Route 53.
- I have CloudFront in front of my AWS server (just running
  WordPress).
- I created an SSL cert in AWS Certificate Manager and associated it with my domain via CloudFront.
- I can access instantaudiobook.co via https. But the browser gives a warning.
  And looking at the certificate, I see it's considered self-signed. It should be signed by Amazon. How do I fix this?

Comment: Hard to say, the details you've provided haven't really given us much to work with. Why don't you share the domain so we can take a peek?

Comment: I'm not showing `instantaudio.co` as a registered domain.

Comment: @ceejayoz OOPS! Fixed. The domain is instantaudiobook.co.

Comment: I show that domain pointed at the IP `34.198.237.15`, which appears to be an EC2 instance (`nslookup` of `ec2-34-198-237-15.compute-1.amazonaws.com`), not a CloudFront distribution (which would have a `nslookup` along the lines of `server-52-84-86-97.yul62.r.cloudfront.net`).

Comment: OK, so I need to point the domain to ddpk64i44qnn5.cloudfront.net?

(Hitting that domain directly I get "CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin. ") I guess I must have CloudFront setup wrong?

Comment: Yeah, if that's your distribution, you've got something wrong in the setup, and you haven't pointed the domain at it either. You're seeing the certificate from your EC2 instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65662/discussion-between-brad-rhoads-and-ceejayoz).

Comment: I finally figured out the problem was I needed to change my A records to be an ALIAS of ddpk64i44qnn5.cloudfront.net. 

If you want to put this all together as an answer, I'll accept it.